# Search a folder and sub folders for files starting with criteria

Tags: python

I have a folder "c:\test" , the folder "test" contains many sub folders and files (.xml, .wav). I need to search all folders for files in the test folder and all sub-folders, starting with the number 4 and being 7 characters long in it and copy these files to another folder called 'c:\test.copy' using python. any other files need to be ignored.

So far i can copy the files starting with a 4 but not structure to the new folder using the following,

```
from glob import glob

import os, shutil

root_src_dir = r'C:/test'    #Path of the source directory
root_dst_dir = 'c:/test.copy'  #Path to the destination directory

for file in glob('c:/test/**/4*.*'):
shutil.copy(file, root_dst_dir)
```

any help would be most welcome

Comment: Are you looking to copy just the files into one single directory or are you looking to also copy all of the folders that contain files that meet the criteria? For example, if the directory you're searching has a subfolder `foo` with a file `4xxxxxxx.yyy`, should you also copy the folder `foo` to the new directory or just the file?

Comment: correct. so i have folder a which has subfolders 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.(then another folder going 1-99 and so on). some folders contain a file starting with 4 some have files containing files starting with other numbers or letters. I need to copy just the files starting with 4 to the new folder but keep the original folder structure they were in to start with. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `os` and `shutil` modules:

```
import os
import shutil
```

Firstly, we need to establish the source and destination paths. `source` should the be the directory you are copying and `destination` should be the directory you want to copy into.

```
source = r"/root/path/to/source"
destination = r"/root/path/to/destination"
```

Next, we have to check if the `destination` path exists because `shutil.copytree()` will raise a `FileExistsError` if the `destination` path already exists. If it does already exist, we can remove the tree and duplicate it again. You can think of this block of code as simply refreshing the duplicate directory:

```
if os.path.exists(destination):
    shutil.rmtree(destination)
shutil.copytree(source, destination)
```

Then, we can use `os.walk` to recursively navigate the entire directory, including subdirectories:

```
for path, _, files in os.walk(destination):
    for file in files:
        if not file.startswith("4") and len(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) != 7:
            os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))
    if not os.listdir(path):
        os.rmdir(path)
```

We then can loop through the files in each directory and check if the file does not meet your condition (starts with "4" and has a length of 7). If it does not meet the condition, we simply remove it from the directory using `os.remove`.

The final `if-statement` checks if the directory is now empty. If the directory is empty after removing the files, we simply delete that directory using `os.rmdir`.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```py
import os
import shutil

root_src_dir = r'C:/test'    #Path of the source directory
root_dst_dir = 'c:/test.copy'  #Path to the destination directory

for root, _, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("4") and len(file) == 7:
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), root_dst_dir)
```

If, by 7 characters, you mean 7 characters without the file extension, then replace `len(file) == 7` with `len(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) == 7`.

Comment: that works thank you, i just need to keep the folder structure now